# PM2 does not restart Node JS application when this error occurs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pm2

For some reason, every time I get this particular error

```
/home/pi/.pm2/logs/app-error.log last 15 lines:
0|scripts | { TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
0|scripts |     at Promise.then (/home/pi/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111) name: 'TimeoutError' }
```

pm2 does not restart the node JS script.

Answer (score 1):

It because that error doesnt crash the main thread of the application, it just prints the error from the puppeteer thread

Comment: But when I get the error script freezes. How am I supposed to stop this behaviour from occurring.

Comment: @user13834264 were you able to fix this?

Comment: @acrogenesis no, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use try...catch statement to catch the error (you can log it or just do nothing) so that the script will not just hang there with the error. pm2 will be able to restart it.